# MS SQL can't do calculations in a select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am looking to find groups of payment records so that I can combine them. For example payments for the same customer, account, etc, but made on the 1st and then the 31st of a month.

I have the following code. It looks for records that have the same customer, agreement, etc and finds the minimum (AGRMT_PMNT_ID) to use as the record to update.

The problem is that the line eap.PMNT_DAY - eap1.PMNT_DAY > 5 doesn’t work. It always returns 0. If I comment out this line, it works but returns the wrong results.

It seems that I can compare columns in a select eg. eap.a = eap1.a, but I can’t do maths (eap.a – eap1.a > 5)

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT *
  FROM TMP_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS  AS eap
  WHERE eap.AGRMT_PMNT_ID = 
     (
        SELECT min(eap1.AGRMT_PMNT_ID) AS expr
        FROM TMP_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS  AS eap1
        WHERE 
           eap.CUSTOMER_ID = eap1.CUSTOMER_ID AND
           eap.AGREEMENT_ID = eap1.AGREEMENT_ID AND
           eap.TXN_CODE = eap1.TXN_CODE AND
           eap.TXN_CORR_ACCOUNT = eap1.TXN_CORR_ACCOUNT AND
           eap.PMNT_DAY - eap1.PMNT_DAY > 5 -- THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
     )
```

Here is some sample data.

```
    AGRMT_PMNT_ID   442530  442531
    CUSTOMER_ID 382100000000000063131   382100000000000063131
    AGREEMENT_ID    38210000000010251257    38210000000010251257 
    PMNT_DAY    3   31
    PMNT_DAY1   34  0
    PMNT_AMOUNT 597.37  597.37
```

You can see that AGRMT_PMNT_ID 442530 and 442531 are for the same customer, agreement, etc. The amount of 597.37 was paid on the 3rd and the 31st.  The intention is to combine these two records data together.

The problem is the code 
        **eap.PMNT_DAY - eap1.PMNT_DAY > 5** 
to check that pmnt_day in record 442530 minus pmnt_day in record 442531 is more than 5, ie. They are more than 5 days apart.

In the select I can compare columns from different records, eg. 
        **eap.CUSTOMER_ID =  eap1.CUSTOMER_ID,**

But I can’t use the columns in calculations
        **eap.PMNT_DAY - eap1.PMNT_DAY > 5**

I think this is just my stupidity, but what am I missing?

UPDATE

The code below does what I require. Thanks for all of your input.

```
SELECT *
  FROM TMP_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS  AS eap
  WHERE eap.AGRMT_PMNT_ID IN 
     (
        SELECT min(eap1.AGRMT_PMNT_ID) AS expr
        FROM TMP_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS  AS eap1, 
             TMP_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS  AS eap2
        WHERE 
           eap2.CUSTOMER_ID = eap1.CUSTOMER_ID AND
           eap2.AGREEMENT_ID = eap1.AGREEMENT_ID AND
           eap2.TXN_CODE = eap1.TXN_CODE AND
           eap2.TXN_CORR_ACCOUNT = eap1.TXN_CORR_ACCOUNT AND
           eap2.PMNT_DAY - eap1.PMNT_DAY > 5 
        GROUP BY eap1.CUSTOMER_ID, eap1.AGREEMENT_ID, 
                 eap1.TXN_CODE, eap1.TXN_CORR_ACCOUNT
 )
```

Comment: What's the data type of PMNT_Day? If it's a date then you'll have to use datediff.

Comment: Its a simple integer, ie. the day the payment was made. So in the code I can see that the days differ by more than 5 days.

I know that I need to do an abs(eap.pmnt_day - eap1.pmnt_day ) to cater for negative results.

Comment: Please add the exact error message SQL gives you. Is it "can't convert boolean to int" ???

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a horrible way to describe a programming problem to developers for help.

Comment: Are you expecting a single result? or many results?

Comment: There is no error message. It simply doesn't return any rows, whereas it returns three rows if this line is commented out.

I appreciate 'doesn't work' is not a good explanation. Sorry.

I am looking for a single result (min) for each group of payments.

Comment: Could you clarify this question with what you are looking to do in layman's terms?

Comment: I agree with layarenee, it would be better if you clarified your intent. If you're trying to compare different payment agreements for the same customer, this query doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I have updated the original question. Hopefully this will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, SLin on the comment is right.

```
DATEDIFF (day, eap1.PMNT_DAY, eap.PMNT_DAY) > 5
```

If it is just integers, you might want to try adding in parentheses around your calculation.

Comment: The actual code is 
abs(eap.PMNT_DAY - eap1.PMNT_DAY) > 5

but this doesn't work

Comment: Put that expression in your select and see what the value actually is.

Comment: Have you tried flipping the expression?  (eap1.PMNT_DAY - eap.PMNT_DAY) > 5

Answer (score 0):

Does this query give you close to what you desire?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TMP_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS eap
INNER JOIN TMP_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS eap1 ON eap.CUSTOMER_ID = eap1.CUSTOMER_ID
           AND eap.AGREEMENT_ID = eap1.AGREEMENT_ID 
           AND eap.TXN_CODE = eap1.TXN_CODE
           AND eap.TXN_CORR_ACCOUNT = eap1.TXN_CORR_ACCOUNT
           AND (eap.PMNT_DAY - eap1.PMNT_DAY) > 5
```

Comment: I will try this. Initially, it doesn't do quite what I want as it gives me all fileds for both records, whereas i really nee the values for the min(agrmt_pmnt_id), but I will investigate tomorrow.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM TMP_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS  AS eap
  WHERE eap.AGRMT_PMNT_ID IN 
     (
        SELECT min(eap1.AGRMT_PMNT_ID) AS expr
        FROM TMP_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS  AS eap1, TMP_AGREEMENT_PAYMENTS  AS eap2
        WHERE 
           eap2.CUSTOMER_ID = eap1.CUSTOMER_ID AND
           eap2.AGREEMENT_ID = eap1.AGREEMENT_ID AND
           eap2.TXN_CODE = eap1.TXN_CODE AND
           eap2.TXN_CORR_ACCOUNT = eap1.TXN_CORR_ACCOUNT AND
           eap2.PMNT_DAY - eap1.PMNT_DAY > 5 
        GROUP BY eap1.CUSTOMER_ID, eap1.AGREEMENT_ID, eap1.TXN_CODE, eap1.TXN_CORR_ACCOUNT
     )